# How do I let bundle know I installed Ruby 1.9.2 on OS X Lion?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, osx-lion

I installed Ruby 1.9.2 on OS X Lion using `brew install ruby` and updated gem to 1.8.11 using `gem update --system`.

However, on my Rails 3 project, bundle is still using the Ruby 1.8 path (/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/Ruby) to install new gems and fails with packages that require Ruby 1.9 (linecache19 in my case).

How do I let bundle know that I installed 1.9.2?

(I tried using RVM to installed Ruby and failed for some reason. The installer simply hand. I think the network connection was too slow or something)

Comment: I strongly recommend you give RVM another try, since it's definitely the best way to manage different versions of rubies, especially on the long run, when you might need to update Ruby itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I retried rvm and it now it works like a charm. Apparently, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a default Ruby with RVM or create a `.rvmrc` in your Rails project? If not, do so and then install the Bundler gem for the correct Ruby version before doing a Bundle install.

Update: I kinda misread your question before. For your system you use Homebrew's Ruby, make sure `/usr/local/bin` comes in your PATH before `/usr/bin` (where the system Ruby lives).

Comment: RVM installation failed repeatedly for some reason. Either download speed was VERY slow or the download wouldn't even start.

Comment: It is and I do get 1.9.2 for  `ruby -v`. Even `gem env` shows paths under the new install (in Homebrew's Cellar). Only under rails with `bundle install` do things seems to get confused.